# Django "POST" request by using button and "Reverse for 'parsepdf' not found. 'parsepdf' is not a valid view function or pattern name." error

Tags: python, django

I pass "dictionary" data to the template
And template HTML code looks like this

```
<h1>PDF paths</h1>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>PDF paths</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <td><B>id</B></td>
            <td><B>uuid</B></td>
            <td><B>user_web_uuid</B></td>
            <td><B>inspectionUploadType</B></td>
            <td><B>uploadRoute</B></td>
            <td><B>createdAt</B></td>
            <td><B>status</B></td>
            <td><B></B></td>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for one_row in out_list %}
        <tr>
            <form action="{% url 'pdfparseapp:parsepdf' %}" method="POST" class="post-form"> {% csrf_token %}
                <td>{{one_row.0}}</td>
                <td>{{one_row.1}}</td>
                <td>{{one_row.2}}</td>
                <td>{{one_row.3}}</td>
                <td>{{one_row.4}}</td>
                <td>{{one_row.5}}</td>
                <td>{{one_row.6}}</td>
                <td><button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Parse</button></td>
            </form>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        <tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

The output screen looks like this
[image]

And if I click "Parse" button, I want to grab "one row data (red squre)" and want to go to another view's function to process data, for example,

```
def process_data(request):
  id=request.POST["id"]
  uuid=request.POST["uuid"]
  user_web_uuid=request.POST["user_web_uuid"]
  inspectionUploadType=request.POST["inspectionUploadType"]
  uploadRoute=request.POST["uploadRoute"]
  createdAt=request.POST["createdAt"]
  status=request.POST["status"]

  # Perform algorithm code using above data.......
```

Project's URL conf and App's URL conf

```
# Project URL conf
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('pdfparseapp.urls'))
]

# App URL conf
app_name="pdfparseapp"
urlpatterns = [
    path('uploadpdfs/', views.pdfView),
    path('parsepdf/', views.parsePdf),
]
```

Since I'm new to web and django, I'm not sure how to do it.
And I got "Reverse for 'parsepdf' not found. 'parsepdf' is not a valid view function or pattern name." error, with above template HTML code
Please guide me.

Comment: Please add your URLConf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the URL viewname as `parsepdf` inside your template:

```
{% url 'pdfparseapp:parsepdf' %}
```

but have not set any in the URLConf, resulting in the error.

So, add the viewname:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('parsepdf/', views.parsePdf, name='parsepdf'),
]
```

Do the same for other URLs that you're doing `reverse` on; if unsure, add to all of them.

Answer (score 0):

To use POST request from template HTML to the Django view, I tried this code using `hidden input tag`

```
<h1>PDF paths</h1>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>PDF paths</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <td><B>id</B></td>
            <td><B>uuid</B></td>
            <td><B>user_web_uuid</B></td>
            <td><B>inspectionUploadType</B></td>
            <td><B>uploadRoute</B></td>
            <td><B>createdAt</B></td>
            <td><B>status</B></td>
            <td><B></B></td>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for one_row in out_list %}
        <tr>
            <form action="{% url 'pdfparseapp:parsepdf' %}" method="POST" class="post-form"> {% csrf_token %}
                <td>{{one_row.0}}</td>
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{one_row.0}}">
                <td>{{one_row.1}}</td>
                <input type="hidden" name="uuid" value="{{one_row.1}}">
                <td>{{one_row.2}}</td>
                <input type="hidden" name="user_web_uuid" value="{{one_row.2}}">
                <td>{{one_row.3}}</td>
                <input type="hidden" name="inspectionUploadType" value="{{one_row.3}}">
                <td>{{one_row.4}}</td>
                <input type="hidden" name="uploadRoute" value="{{one_row.4}}">
                <td>{{one_row.5}}</td>
                <input type="hidden" name="createdAt" value="{{one_row.5}}">
                <td>{{one_row.6}}</td>
                <input type="hidden" name="status" value="{{one_row.6}}">
                <td><button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Parse</button></td>
            </form>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        <tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

And the view which takes above POST request is like this

```
def parsePdf(request):
  id_val=request.POST["id"]
  uuid_val=request.POST["uuid"]
  user_web_uuid_val=request.POST["user_web_uuid"]
  inspectionUploadType_val=request.POST["inspectionUploadType"]
  uploadRoute_val=request.POST["uploadRoute"]
  createdAt_val=request.POST["createdAt"]
  status_val=request.POST["status"]
```